# I want to open a file dialogue and pass the location of selected file as argument to tkinter to show on gui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter

I am facing the problem that the filedialogue is returning _io.TextIOWrapper object while tkinter takes location of the file as string.

I tried every method to convert this _io.TextIOWrapper to string but failed .

Help me out!!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.main = tk.Frame(self)
      self.main.grid(row=0, column=0)

      dial = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile()

      self.disp_img = Image.open(dial).resize((400, 400))
      self.disp_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.disp_img)

      self.img_label = tk.Label(self.main, image=self.disp_img)
      self.img_label.grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = App()
   app.withdraw()
   app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want `askopenfilename()`, not `askopenfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment on the question, you want to use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()`. Alternatively, the `TextIOWrapper` object has a variable called `name` which contains the file name.

Comment: Now its giving no TextIOWrapper  object conversion error and gives me the location of the file in string format, but it doesnt show up on tkinter window.

Comment: 1. Dialogue opens up    2.I select the image 3.It returns the location  4.location passed to tk 4.And application window closes without any error

Comment: I’m confused then. What did you want to do with the file name? What do you mean by display it on the window?

Comment: I want to take the file location from file dialogue and pass it to tkinter to show on window

Comment: So you can set a variable equal to the output of askopenfilename and then put that string in a text widget

Comment: I have done that but what happens is that tkinter window opens and closes just after opening!!